# WPF the display of my listview (from a list) is all over the place. How do I fix this output?

Tags: wpf, list, listview

I have a class that opens text files to grab first name, last name, email address and username.  It does this for multiple files and stores the results in a list.

My code for the list is:

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public List<UserRecord> userRecords = new List<UserRecord>();
}

public class UserRecord
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

The xaml code is:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="Users" SelectionChanged="Users_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Email" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="User Name" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

And lastly I populate the list with this code:

```
List<UserRecord> userRecords = new List<UserRecord>();
userRecords = UFA.getUserData();
Users.DataContext = userRecords;
```

The listview does correctly load the data, however each property (name, email etc) is on a separate line, with several blank lines between records.  Additionally it looks like the properties are being entered into the grid in reverse order of the display (user name first etc).   This is what it shows:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this mess?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well it appears as if I can't remove this question so I'll answer it.   The loop I was using to populate the list was populating its self even when there was no data to add.  I just moved to the two lines outside of the loop and problem solved..